# User can access page via URL if they do not log out and simply close the tab

Tags: php, session, cookies

In the same browser "session":
I have a Login Page.
User access a Menu Page if successfully logged in.
If user log out from Menu Page.
It is not possible to access Menu Page with URL or even going back.
However if user just closed (Not Log Out) Menu_Page tab with Browser still open.
The User can access Menu Page from url in another tab in browser.

If browser is completely closed and then reopen, Menu Page cannot be accessed with url.

But if browser is still open and Menu Page tab closed only.

User can access same without Log in again with Url.

How can I prevent this.

Comment: Those are the rules. If you forget to manually logout, your session close only when the browser window close( if there is no login cookie ). I like the fact that I can remain logged-in after closing the tab and can return later without having to login again( as long as timed logout does not exist )

Comment: That is actually very interesting. I know how it works now and I'm gonna use it.

Comment: how much would you say would be an appropriate amount set before log out?

Comment: 30 minutes of inactivity. My bank website is far less : I think it has 5 or 10 minutes

Comment: I just read your discussion with @KIKO Software and decided to add something - I've came across very few websites that make use of timed logout :  e.g. my bank and website host. Assuming that your site is not as sensitive as these you can do without timed logout( it brings poor user experience. Users have a responsibility to manual logout ).

Comment: Yes indeed. One just has to weight the pros and cons of a timed logout. (Even if that also is not foolproof.) Responsible user behavior is the only way to security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. This has to do with your cookie, probably a session cookie. See:

https://www.php.net/function.setcookie

here it says under **expires**:

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

So only when the browser closes will the cookie, with an expire time set to zero, be deleted.

I can only think of quite elaborated ways around this, which will never be 100% reliable, so I'm not even going to suggest them.

Comment: Yeah. It would have been interesting to have such a feature though... But then again its like blocking cookies and not being able to even  log in. The timed log out suggestion is good though. How much time would be appropriate before automatic log out IYO?

Comment: @WhiteRose Yes, a time-out would work, but it could annoy the hell out of your users as well. I use some systems that time-out after 15 minutes or an hour, and they are annoying. If I get interrupted by a phone call, or something similar, and I return to my work I find that I was logged out. I can image sites where a 15 minute time-out would be long, but most of the time an user leaves a page open with the intention to return to it.

Comment: For the sake of argument, would you say that security wins over user-friendliness? In my scenario, that person did not leave the page open. She just closed the tab instead of logging out and did not close the browser. if some other person would access that browser and used the page url to access same. Wouldn't that be a security issue. I know there are a lot of If's but its a pretty plausible scenario.

Comment: If that's the case, then even the timed logout would not work as the tab would have been closed before the time out.

Comment: I agree, that is a plausible scenario. But if your time-out is set to 15 minutes, would this scenario become less plausible? A bit perhaps, but it is still possible. There is no solution for bad user behaviour. You could warn them: "Always log off, or close your browser.", but will that help? I don't think so. Can we blame the browser? Hmm, yes, perhaps, but as hans-könig already mentioned, it is also a nice feature in some cases.

Comment: Yes. It is a nice feature when the user is responsible enough to log out appropriately if away for a long time.